# Difference between a push / pull and commit in source tree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Is it possible to see the difference between a push / pull and a commit in the log view in SourceTree?

Comment: what do you want? compare a push (action) to a commit (state)?

Comment: "push" = "send a set of commits and the objects they point to to a remote"; "pull" = "copy a set of commits and referred objects from a remote"; "commit" = "create a new snapshot of the project, pointing to updated directories, files, etc. and one or more parent commits"... I can't even imagine a useful way to display the differences between those three concepts...

Comment: @BreakoBreako maybe we can help you more if you explain ***why*** you want to see "the difference between push/pulls and commits". ***What are you trying to do***, what goal are you trying to accomplish, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Cupcake I am coming from a SVn background when it was clear to me when files were changed and who changed them. If sourcetree does not show Push and Pull then it is difficult to find out when files were changed.

Comment: @BreakoBreako if all you want to do is see what changes people have made to a branch, you can just `fetch`, then view the log of whatever remote-tracking branches you have, like `origin/master` for example. That will tell you what files changed and who changed them. Also, have you read the [free online Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book)? It may help clarify the concepts of commits, pushes, pulls, and fetches for you.

Comment: @Cupcake  How do you fetch in SourceTree?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky http://i.stack.imgur.com/CTktk.png

Answer (score 39):

a commit is saving the state of your code into version control

http://git.github.io/git-reference/basic/#commit

a push is sending your commited coded to a remote server (e.g. github)

http://git.github.io/git-reference/remotes/#push

a fetch is downloading the newest changes from a remote server to your local repository, but keeping your repo as is.

http://git.github.io/git-reference/remotes/#fetch

a pull is downloading the newest changes from a remote server to your local repository and checking out the newest code from the repo.

http://git.github.io/git-reference/remotes/#pull

Comment: I know but when I look at the log in SourceTree is it possible to tell the push from the commits etc

Comment: log will only *ever* show commits. push, pull, and fetch are just syncing commands.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes** it is possible to see the difference between a push / pull and a commit in the log view in SourceTree. In this screenshot, everything between `test` and `origin/test` is your local commit log:

[image: SourceTree git log view with diff between pull and commit]

*Selecting both labels, the changes show that I've twice committed an edit of the same comment, explaining the 2 pushable commits.*

After you modify more without committing, and others push their commits, it can look like this:

[image: SourceTree git log view with ahead/behind info]

`origin/test` is now 2 commits ahead of our (now red) `test` branch `HEAD` that was pulled from the 807... commit and has not been merged (by push or pull) into `origin/test` yet. This becomes more obvious when selecting `Ancestor Order`:

[image: SourceTree git log view with ahead/behind info and Ancestor Order graph]